# a lot of packet loss and bandwidth decrease in my crafted tunnel protocol

Tags: go, networking, tcp, vpn

I am designing my own vpn tunnel protocol which is at this point very simple
I connect my mac to a server in an abroad datacenter with ubuntu 22.04 and my packets pass through that server and goes to the internet, I explain what happens to a single packet in this flow.
I create a tunel interface, say utun5 in my mac (using water library in go)  which I set as default gateway so all packets go through this interface.
Then I capture every packet receivng by this interface and send them through a tcp channel that I already established between my client and server. I also add a entry in routing table for packets that I send to my server to go through physical interface and not utun so I don't lose my tcp channel.
the following code is how I capture packets in the client and send them to server

```
func handleSendPackets(ifce *water.Interface, key []byte, conn net.Conn) {
    packetBuf := make([]byte, BUFFER_SIZE)
    var totalBytes int
    for {
        n, _ := ifce.Read(packetBuf)
        totalBytes += n
        fmt.Println(totalBytes / 1000)
        handleBuf := func(buf []byte) {
            ipHeader, err := ipv4.ParseHeader(packetBuf[:n])
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            if ipHeader.Flags > 0 {
                fmt.Println(ipHeader)
            }
            subnet := net.IPNet{IP: net.ParseIP("10.0.10.0"), Mask: net.CIDRMask(24, 32)}
            if subnet.Contains(ipHeader.Dst) {
                fmt.Println("containes")
                return
            } else {

                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Failed to encrypt the packet:", err)
                    return
                }
                _, err = conn.Write(buf)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error sending packet to server:", err)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        go handleBuf(packetBuf[:n])

    }
}
```

then in the server when I receive the packets I write them to tun0 interface that I created and I also already set up NAT rules to send this pakcets that I write to tun0 to the internet with src ip of my server, then when the response packet of the sent packet comes, it sends it back to tun0 and from the local ip of the packet I find the corresponding user tcp connection and write the response packet to the user connection.

code that handles reading packets from client connection and send them to tun0, hence to the internet

```
buf := make([]byte, BUFFER_SIZE)
    var totalBytes int
    for {

        n, _ := conn.Read(buf)
        totalBytes += n
        fmt.Println(totalBytes / 1000)
        packets := extractIPPackets(buf[:n])
        // pkt, err := decrypt(session.SharedKey, buf[:n])
        // if err != nil {
        //  continue
        // }

        for _, p := range packets {
            go server.TunnelInterface.Write(p)

        }

    }
```

code that handles sending response packets back to the user

```
// handles the reponses from internet that comes to the tunnel interface of the server
func handleServerIncomingResponses(server Server) {
    buffer := make([]byte, BUFFER_SIZE)
    var totalBytes int
    for {
        n, err := server.TunnelInterface.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                continue // Ignore EOF errors and keep reading
            }
            log.Print("Failed to read from TUN interface:", err)
        }
        totalBytes += n
        fmt.Println("received: ", totalBytes/1000)
        packet := buffer[:n]
        h, _ := ipv4.ParseHeader(buffer[:n])
        fmt.Println(h)
        go routeServerIncomingResponses(server, packet)
    }
}

func routeServerIncomingResponses(server Server, packet []byte) {

    ipHeader, err := ipv4.ParseHeader(packet)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    subnet := net.IPNet{IP: net.ParseIP("10.0.10.0"), Mask: net.CIDRMask(24, 32)}
    if subnet.Contains(ipHeader.Dst) {
        id, err := IPToID(ipHeader.Dst, server.BaseLocalIP)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        var conn net.Conn
        _, ok := server.Sessions[id]
        if ok {
            conn = *server.Sessions[id].Conn
            conn.Write(packet)
        }

        // encrypted, err := encrypt(server.Sessions[id].SharedKey, packet)

    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

then In the client I write the response to utun5 again and it is being processed by network stack and the connection is established.

What is the problem now? the problem is that my connection bandwidth for both client and server is more than 1Gbps, but when I use the tunnel software it become less than 1mbps!!

I also monitored it with wireshark and realized there are many times tcp retransmission happens (not the tcp connection between client and server, but if one of my apps use tcp, for exampel chrome or discord)
any idea on what is the issue?

Comment: Ignoring `io.EOF` and continuing to read will just turn into a busy loop, you need a way to exit that loop. Switching back and forth in and out of userspace on every packet like this is very inefficient, you need to profile to find out where your real bottlenecks are (doing things like adding multiple slow `fmt.Print*` calls for every single packet are going to have a big impact). The "encryption" pattern here looks very suspect, and at worse is trivially broken, why not use any of the well tested exitsing tunnel solutions?

Comment: those prints are just for the sake of debuging and will be removed, 
either way, I tested the tcp connection strength between two pairs with sending big and numerous ping packets and it seems to work fine (I get maximum expecter troughput), but when the packets go out from the server and come back from the internet, there probaly is something wrong. I can't use any existing solution for this for some reasons.

Comment: also can you please explain why the context switch happens here? and is there a way to avoid it? 
does `interface.write()` function trigger a context switch?

Comment: What context switch are you referring to? You can't avoid some context switching when making syscalls like this, that's why making TCP efficient relies on buffering to allow for larger reads and writes. More issues to consider, you appear to be spawning a new goroutine for every single "packet" (do these actually correspond with packets, or are these just what was buffered?) which a huge amount of overhead per read/write. Since this is a stream, why are you using concurrent goroutines in the first place, and how are you going to fix the order of chunks when they are re-ordered randomly?

Comment: Thanks. I use cuncurrent goroutines to avoid delays, in a way that every new packet I recieve I trigger the handler function as a new go routine so reading the next packet is not blocked, is that a bad idea?
Either way I also tried it without the go routines (removed go keyword) and yet issue exists.
Right now, my problem is to get it working rather than optimize it for resource usage.

Comment: using goroutines for each chunk read from a stream makes no sense because processing a stream is a serial operation. You are adding a ton of scheduling overhead, stack allocation, not to mention the order the bytes are transferred is now non-deterministic. There are too many variables for anyone to help here, especially without a [mre]. If you are trying to get a functional example, get rid of as much complexity as possible.

Comment: Ok makes sense, I got rid of go routines. 
though I don't really know how to make it simpler for debugging and making it minimal. I think it is already minimal, but naturally this software is a bit complex.